# keep getting query failed

Tags: php, mysqli

As a note, I do not know PHP very well. This a school project and they had me take a different class instead of the php I was suppose to take.

That being said I have the below query I am trying to run and I keep getting query failed and I do not get why. I've been following tutorials step by step. The database is connecting but the query is still failing.

```
<!doctype html>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "krystalb_krystal";
$password = "";
$dbname = "krystalb_Sales_Tracking";


// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";


?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
 <?php
    //query
    $sql="SELECT * FROM customer ORDER BY customer.CUST_LAST_NAME;";
    $res=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if(!$res)
    {
        die("Query failed!");
    }
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($res))
    {
        var_dump($row);
        echo "<br /><hr /><br />";
        mysqli_free_result($res);
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I honestly dont even know how to turn errors on so I can read them.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and 
 other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: if you look at the code if set up an if statement.

Comment: K I found the error Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: No database selected in /home/krystalb/public_html/PRG240GA/sales_tracking.php:24 Stack trace: #0 /home/krystalb/public_html/PRG240GA/sales_tracking.php(24): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'SELECT * FROM c...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/krystalb/public_html/PRG240GA/sales_tracking.php on line 24

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead;

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "krystalb_krystal";
$password = "";
$dbname = "krystalb_Sales_Tracking";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname) or die('Unable to select Database');
global $conn;  //Just in-case you need to use the connection inside a function, class, etc
```